# Issue with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, web-services, afnetworking

My client webservice send me a result like this:

```
{"login":{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"}}
```

So, in AFN doesn't work.

But, if have one more result works:

```
{"login":[{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"},{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"}]}
```

My code:

```
NSDictionary *paramLogin = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtEmail.text, @"email",_txtSenha.text, @"senha", nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager GET:@"http://webservice.info" parameters:paramLogin success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@" , responseObject );

    for (NSDictionary *retLogin in [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"login"]) {

        nome  = [retLogin objectForKey:@"nome"];
        email = [retLogin objectForKey:@"email"];


    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

why it is like this? or what I've to do ?

Comment: In what way does it 'not work'? Show the code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes `[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"login"]` returns and array, sometimes it returns a dictionary. You need to test for this.

```
id loginValue = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"login"];

if ([loginValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    nome  = [loginValue objectForKey:@"nome"];
    email = [loginValue objectForKey:@"email"];
} else if ([loginValue isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (NSDictionary *retLogin in [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"login"]) {

        nome  = [retLogin objectForKey:@"nome"];
        email = [retLogin objectForKey:@"email"];


    }
} else {
    // ERROR: Unexpected value
}
```

When you have 1 value, then `loginValue` is an NSDictionary. It contains `{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"}`.

When you have more than 1 value, then `loginValue` is an NSArray. The array contains `[<NSDictionary>, <NSDictionary>]`. Each of of these dictionaries contains `{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"}`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting response like that than use below code

```
NSMutableArray *category = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
category = [responseObject objectForKey:@"login"];

 for(int i = 0; i < [category count]; i++)
 {
    NSDictionary *dic = [category objectAtIndex:i]; 
    nome  = [dic objectForKey:@"nome"];
    email = [dic objectForKey:@"email"];
 }
```

Comment: this is not needed with AFNetworking. response data is already a `NSDcitionary`

Comment: responseObject is always a `NSDictionary`, first object in that dictionary is an array. Eitherway, no need of using a JSON Serializer because AFNetworking library does that for you already.

Comment: yaa he need to store first object in array that is what i want to say.. i have edited ans

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your json data structure. It's not consistent.

```
{"login":{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"}}
```

Here `[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"login"]` is a single `NSDictionary` object.

But here,

```
{"login":[{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"},{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"}]}
```

Here `[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"login"]` is an `NSArray`. So your fast enumeration works.

Best solution is to ask your webservice developer to send an array all the time, even 'login' has a single object. so it should look like this,

```
{"login": [{"EMAIL":"none","ID":"none","NOME":"none"}]}  //notice square brackets
```

Otherwise you have to modify your code to check for an `NSDictionary` instead of array when there's only one object.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you aren't retaining the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` object.

Assuming this code is in something like `viewDidAppear`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:...];
```

Then `manager` will be destroyed before it has a chance to complete.

Instead add a property and store the manager object in that:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;
@end
```

and use:

```
self.manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[self.manager GET:...];
```